# Can I switch from "man's" to "yours" in this paragraph?

Tags: writing-style

> Locke thinks that property right is naturally attached to man's labor.
>   That is, the products of your interaction with the natural world
>   naturally belongs to you.(self-made)

In the first sentence I use "man's", in the second I switch to "your" and "you", I doubt that "you" may make the sentence a particular statement pointing to one particular subject, thus making the whole paragraph sound like not a theoritical writing, but a cathartic expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of "your" and "you" is fine. If it bothers you at all, you could change it to "a person's" and "that person" (or "one's" and "that person").

You may want to avoid "man" because it may be perceived as sexist. Writers who seek gender neutrality in language try to use words like "humankind." In this case, since you are using the possessive form ("man's"), you could substitute the adjective "human." You could even omit the possessive altogether and preserve the same sense.

> Locke thinks that property right is naturally attached to labor.

Again, you could also use a more general possessive pronoun like "one's."

> Locke thinks that property right is naturally attached to one's labor.

Comment: I'd have to say singular *property right* sounds really odd to me here. Google Books has just 37 instances of [**that property right is**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that+property+right+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22that+property+right+is%22&start=30&tbm=bks), whereas it claims there are 138,000 written instances of [**that property rights are**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that+property+rights+are%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Locke gives us a strong theory of property right so that we can enjoy property rights now.

Comment: Instead of "that person" at the end of the sentence, another option would be to use "them." Hurray for singular they!

Comment: There are other inconsistencies – the products ... belongs and the implicit assumption that the same polyseme appears in 'natural world' and 'naturally belongs'. I disagree that this assumption is [valid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/natural) – which I'd say leaves us with poor juxtaposition or even obscurantism.

Comment: Actually, I was not comforable with the hodgepodge use of "natural". I tried "legitimately", but since proprety right is a natural right, that word is also a poor choice. Maybe I can say "rightly"?

Comment: I think "naturally" is fine because you are talking about natural rights. You could also use the phrase "by nature." That makes the philosophical nuance even more clear.

Comment: Replacing "man's" with "humankind's" or "human" is not correct. Locke is saying that a *particular* man's property rights are tied to that *particular* man's labor, not that the property rights of the entirety of the human race are tied to the labor of the entirety of the human race.